# How to draw a tree view in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Can anybody tell me how to draw a tree view from relational Database in crystal reports?

Comment: pretty sure it would have to have a limit on it's depth. Otherwise it's just a tricky use of groupings and line objects. Need more detail.

Comment: You don't have to limit its depth. Set a grouping on the primary key of the parent, then right click, Reports->Hierarchical Grouping, pick that group you just created, and select the FK that points to the parent's primary ID. Voila

Comment: Hi Yablargo! I m new to SAP Crystal Reports and I m learning it, I m using 2011 trial version. I want to get a tree view of my hierarchial data in SQL server. I could connect to the SQL and get my data but I don't know how to display them in expandible/collapsible like tree structure. Any thoughts? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Try Report | Hierarchical Grouping Options...